# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular

Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded  ./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded